# Share Win10 IE 11 cookie with all users on PC

Tags: cookies, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a web product that integrates with a another product that runs on Win10 PCs. The core product launches an IE 11 browser session calling to my URL. The core product has a VERY basic parameter set such that I need to setup a local cookie to hold additional configuration data that can be read by my site when the PC connects. Due to how IE is launched on the PC, this configuration needs to be done once per user that logs into the PC. I need an easier way to get the cookie data into every user that uses the PC instead of requiring each user to perform the action that causes the core application to launch my page, stop their process, change to a config screen, enter all the config data, save it, return to the prior screen, and then test the process.

Thoughts? I HAVE to use a cookie and I HAVE to store the configuration data in the cookie due to the core application limitations and site requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: I can not install any browser add-ons. I was "hoping" that a powershell script could do this as in: log into PC as user 1, perform action resulting in creation of cookie, {stuff I don't know}, run powershell script to install cookie for all other users, PROFIT.

Comment: Your issue looks like a development requirement. Your description is also confusing. We don't know anything about your application which are involved. we don't know the technologies it uses. Also you did not provided any code sample which you had tried on your side. In that case, it can be hard for us to provide accurate suggestions. I suggest you to provide detailed information about the issue with sample code and detailed steps for reproducing it. It may help us to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It is a question on how to move one user's cookie data for one specific site to all other users on the same workstation. I outlined why I need to do this to give some background. It is not actually relevant to the problem. I have tried nothing as I could find nothing online that comes close to this specific problem. I need to setup a cookie to store process specific data. I need to push my cookie to all users on the PC to avoid having to repeat a complicated web based configuration across all PC users (which could be 10 or more people). I am asking how. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie is created for specific user on a machine.

It did not designed for sharing that data with other users whether on same machine or on same work station.

So it looks like your approach for solving this specific problem is not correct. You can try to rethink about it and try to use any other way for sharing the data between the users on same work station.

If you continue with this approach than it can cause security related issues.

I tried to find but did not got any useful information for sharing the cookie between users on same work station.

Reference:

[Can one cookie be shared by multiple users logged on to the same device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176603/can-one-cookie-be-shared-by-multiple-users-logged-on-to-the-same-device)

Comment: Thank you for that information. Would there be a way to use Powershell to extract the cookie data and then create a new cookie for each other user that exists on that system? So instead of copying the cookie, create new ones based on the information in the original cookie?