# Is Http Cookie per user or per machine?

Tags: http, setcookie, httpcookie

For example, 2 users use the same machine (logged in with different name), will they share the same cookie if they visit the same web page?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176603/can-one-cookie-be-shared-by-multiple-users-logged-on-to-the-same-device

Answer (score 1):

The cookies will be per browser, per machine.

(unless they have multiple user accounts set up at the OS level that they log in to)